# how to programmatically create list of org-roam nodes with given tag?

Tags: org-mode, org-roam, tags

I'd like to create (`meta`) node that contains all references to nodes given `org roam tag`.

For example, Let's say I've tens of `org-roam-nodes` about python-programming-language (each node has tag `python`). Then I create `meta` python node, in which I'd like to have list of references to all those previous nodes.

- How do I programmatically do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found following solution:

### Solution 1: using `shell`

It filters from `org-roam.db` with tag: `:python:` (make it `"%:python:%"`) in the `properties` field into `csv`. Then change the format it into org-mode syntax links.

```shell
#+begin_src shell :results raw
sqlite3 -header -csv ~/.config/emacs/org-roam.db "select id,title from nodes where properties like '%:python:%';" |  sed -e 's/^"""/- [[id:/g' -e 's/""","""/][/g' -e 's/"""$/]]/g'
#                                                                                                      ^tag^                   
#+end_src
```

```org
#+RESULTS:
id,title
- [[id:561668fb-3c32-4255-b58d-bbe3c7d7b4a4][python pyinstaller]]
- [[id:06598602-ce7d-45ee-b519-d6afb9ea8eae][python numpy]]
- [[id:e5b3702f-63ef-4115-af11-5750556df8af][python regex]]
```

### Solution 2: using `emacs`

Exact same with previous step, only using `org-roam-db-query` function (instead of using external `shell`). But not sure how to translate the output into `org-mode` links yet (I'm not that skillful with `elisp`).

```elisp
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(org-roam-db-query
 [
  :select [id, title]
  :from nodes
  :where (like properties '"%:python:%")
  ]
 )
#+end_src
```

```
#+RESULTS:
| 561668fb-3c32-4255-b58d-bbe3c7d7b4a4 | python pyinstaller |
| 06598602-ce7d-45ee-b519-d6afb9ea8eae | python numpy       |
| e5b3702f-63ef-4115-af11-5750556df8af | python regex       |
| 62294da7-6acd-439d-96b4-6817ff345f53 | meta python        |
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this library: [org-roam-ql](https://github.com/ahmed-shariff/org-roam-ql), which enables versatile query and provides a convenient dynamic block. For example, to select nodes with a certain tag and have level greater than 0, one can have:

```
#+BEGIN: org-roam-ql :query (and (tags "some-tag-name") (not (level 0))) :columns (title tags level)
#+END:
```

Then pressing `C-c` `C-c` will populate the block with a table of the queried nodes.

The official example is [here](https://github.com/ahmed-shariff/org-roam-ql?tab=readme-ov-file#org-dynamic-block)